# Creating session variable automatically creates a cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-variables

the problem as in the Title. I thought that session variables are stored in the memory and the only cookie creates is SessionID cookie. For some reason every time I create session variable it also creates a cookie with the same name. Is it normal behavior?

Code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[varName.ToString()] = value;
```

Comment: Here's some [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) regarding session state.  Read the section on 'Cookieless SessionIDs'.  It looks like you can disable cookies if that is what you desire.

Comment: It is normal to have one cookie session.

It is not normal to have for every variable of the session a cookie with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal behavior?

Yes, it is absolutely normal. By default sessions are tracked by cookies. So when you store something into the session a cookie with an unique id is emitted to the client so that on subsequent requests this client sends the cookie and the server is able to retrieve whatever it stored in memory using this id.

If on subsequent requests you update the session value there won't be a new cookie. The session is already associated with this client.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Creating a SessionID cookie is normal, but for some reason it also creates a cookie with the same name as a session variable. Is that normal too?

Comment: No, that's not normal and it shouldn't happen. So you are saying that after invoking a controller action containing the line of code you have shown in your question you, 2 cookies are created? By the way why are you using `HttpContext.Current`? You should never use that. Use the abstractions that the framework provides you to access the session.